# WebSphere 8.5.5: JVMJ9VM007E Command-line option unrecognised: -Xcheck:dump

Tags: websphere, startup, websphere-8, jdk1.7

After updating WebSphere 8.5.5 to the use 1.7 JDK the following error appears in `native_stderr.log` and the server won't start. I presume this option is configured somewhere, but I can't see where.

```
JVMJ9VM007E Command-line option unrecognised: -Xcheck:dump
```

Comment: Could it be defined in Servers->Application servers-><server name>->Java and process management->Process definition->Java virtual machine, under "Generic JVM arguments"?

Comment: No - it isn't there.

Comment: I am going to have to scan the FS for it, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading WebSphere to 8.5.5 fix pack 2 or above, if a server is using Java 7 and the optional Java 7 service release is not also updated (as recommended), WebSphere will fail to start. This is the Known WebSphere Issue. You need to upgrade the IBM Java version of your webSphere server.

Pls look into [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21692797) Link.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a hurry, the start-up options can be found under this folder:

```
$WAS_HOME/properties/systemlaunch/...
```

for example:

```
.../systemlaunch/base/linux/ia64/1.6_64.systemlaunch.properties
```

or similar named file.

Answer (score 0):

A recent change introduced -Xcheck:dump to the application server arguments which will not be recognized prior to Java 7 SR4.  Update Java to the latest version to avoid this conflict.